# In Illustrator, how do you branch off from an existing line with the pen tool?

Tags: pen-tool

I am just starting to try graphic design. I created a shape, and want to make a new line branching off from a point on that shape. I noticed the + sign next to the pen icon and it creates a new anchor, but how do you make a line from that new point? It just keeps on making a new point when I try to click away from it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchor points can only have 2 paths connected to them in Illustrator, and in and an out. You can not connect more than 2 path segments to any anchor point.

the + does indeed mean "add new anchor point" but generally, that means that new anchor already has an "in" and "out' path so you can't add another one.

From reading things, it would appear you just need to draw a *new* path and align it with your existing path.